# What is an alternative of System.Net.WebClient.UploadString in System.Net.Http.HttpClient namespace for WinRT?

Tags: .net, network-programming, windows-runtime, httpclient, webclient

I am working on porting an application from WPF to a Windows 8 App.

I would like to know if there is a similar functionality like `System.Net.WebClient.UploadString` in `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` namespace (since `System.Net.WebClient` isn't available in `WinRT`) If yes an example is greatly appreciated! If not is there any alternative?

On the side note I was able to convert `WebClient.DownloadString` to its equivalent using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` namespace with the help of Morten Nielsen post here http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2011/10/05/WinRT-vs-Silverlight-Part-7-Making-WebRequests.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would use the [`PostAsync` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138242.aspx).

The method takes either a [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) or a string (just like the [`UploadString` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadstring.aspx) on the WebClient class) as well as an [`HttpContent` instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.aspx).

The `HttpContent` instance is meant to be agnostic to different types of content, allowing you to specify not only the mechanism by which you provide the content ([`ByteArrayContent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.bytearraycontent.aspx) for an array of bytes, [StreamContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.streamcontent.aspx) for a [`Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx), etc.) but the structure as well (MultipartFormDataContent).

That said, there is also a [`StringContent` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.stringcontent.aspx) which will send the string, like so:

// The content.
string post = "your content to post";

```
// The client.
using (client = new HttpClient());
{
    // Post.
    // Let's assume you're in an async method.
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.Post(
        "http://yourdomain/post", new StringContent(post));

    // Do something with the response.
}
```

If you need to specify an [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx), [there's a constructor that takes an `Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158992.aspx), which you would use like this:

```
// The client.
using (client = new HttpClient());
{
    // Post.
    // Let's assume you're in an async method.
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.Post(
        "http://yourdomain/post", new StringContent(post),
         Encoding.ASCII);

    // Do something with the response.
}
```

From there, it's a matter of processing the [`HttpResponseMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.aspx) (if that's important to you, if it's not a one-way operation) when the response is sent.